# Scraping email id from website

Tags: r, email, web-scraping, rvest

I am learning web scraping and want to get email_id from this website http://www.barnehagefakta.no/barnehage/1019871/oraker-barnehage-as
I am using css selector to find it in R language

```
library('rvest')
url <- "http://www.barnehagefakta.no/barnehage/1019871/oraker-barnehage-as"
page <- read_html(url)
name_html <- html_nodes(page,'.icon-mail-alt.ng-binding')
df <- data.frame(html_children(name_html) %>% html_attr("href"))
```

Kindly tell what I need to alter.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `.icon-mail-alt.ng-binding` with `a[href^='mailto:']`?

Comment: No it still says empty character.

Comment: I work with different language so can't give you the exact solution. However, the selector I've provided you will definitely fetch you the content you are expecting. If `r` can handle dynamically generated content, that's okay otherwise all you need to do is use a browser simulator like selenium to get that dynamically generated content. Hope it helps. Btw, I've tested with the selector and found the result so you can count on that.

Comment: Alright. No I am not using dynamically generated content. That's the issue then. Thanks